# display existing values of database into formfields

Tags: django-models, django-forms, django-views

How can i get data from **databse(sqllite)** into dropdown button and based on selected value retrive all matching values on datagrid or in csv in django

```
class AnalyzedFile(models.Model):

    sha256 = models.CharField(db_column='SHA256', max_length=64, blank=True)  
    md5 = models.CharField(db_column='MD5', max_length=32, blank=True) 
    sha1 = models.CharField(db_column='SHA1', max_length=40, blank=True) 
    filename = models.CharField(db_column='FILENAME', max_length=5000, blank=True)
    filelength = models.IntegerField(db_column='FILELENGTH', blank=True, null=True) 
    filetype = models.CharField(db_column='FILETYPE', max_length=3, blank=True)
    fileentropy = models.CharField(db_column='FILEENTROPY', max_length=50, blank=True)  
    peidsig = models.CharField(db_column='PEIDSIG', max_length=1000, blank=True)  
    exeinfosig = models.CharField(db_column='EXEINFOSIG', max_length=1000, blank=True)
    ssdeepsig = models.CharField(db_column='SSDEEPSIG', max_length=200, blank=True) 
    digitalsig = models.CharField(db_column='DIGITALSIG', max_length=100, blank=True) 
    description = models.CharField(db_column='DESCRIPTION', max_length=65000, blank=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    analysis = models.CharField(db_column='ANALYSIS', max_length=65000, blank=True)  
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'ANALYZED_FILE'
```

Comment: After code in view like AnalyzedFile.objects.all(), it give me error like no field Analyzed_File.id, beacuse i used existing databse , not created with django syncdb. so i am new in django , please give me solution hoe to add values of databse into dropdown menu and after selecting the perticular option it will again search into databse and give result in csv or datagrid

Comment: solved the problem.......